# I need help on XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, wso2

This is the payload to transform :

```
<result>
<invoice0>201762133</invoice0> 
<invoice1>201730800</invoice1>
<invoice2>2016419446</invoice2>
<totalAmmount0>10208.32</totalAmmount0> 
<totalAmmount1>10196.62</totalAmmount1>
<totalAmmount2>10196.62</totalAmmount2>
<status0>Open</status0> 
<status1>Open</status1>
<status2>Closed</status2>
<date0>30/03/2017</date0>
<date1>28/02/2017</date1>
<date2>30/01/2017</date2>
<invoiceAmmount>3</invoiceAmmount> 
</result>
```

So, I can't change this payload before the transformation, and I'm not managing to delivery this way:

```
<result>
<invoiceNumber>201762133,201730800,2016419446</invoiceNumber> 
<totalAmmount>10208.32,10196.62,10196.62</totalAmmount>
<statusInvoice>Open,Open,Closed</statusInvoice>
<dueDate>30/03/2017,28/02/2017,30/01/2017</dueDate>
<invoiceAmmount>3</invoiceAmmount> 
</result>
```

Question: Is it possible? How?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Made a bit more obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you have a (single) root tag named *results*,
containing:

- A number of *invoice...*, *totalAmmount...*, *status...*
  and *date...* tags, to concatenate into respective target tags.
- A single *invoiceAmmount* tag, just to copy to the output.

Concatenation of a number of source elements, starting with a common prefix
and ending with a numer of digits can be performed using a dedicated template.

It has 2 parameters:

- *sourceTag* - the source element name prefix.
- *targetTag* - the tag name to create.

This template:

- Prints the opening target tag.
- Prints values of source elements matching the given prefix
  and a number of digits.
- Prints the closing target tag.

This template is called 4 times, for source elements named *invoice...*, *totalAmmount...*, *status...* and *date...*, with respective target tag names.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="result">
    <result>
      <xsl:call-template name="cumulate">
        <xsl:with-param name="sourceTag" select="'invoice'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="targetTag" select="'invoiceNumber'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="cumulate">
        <xsl:with-param name="sourceTag" select="'totalAmmount'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="targetTag" select="'totalAmmount'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="cumulate">
        <xsl:with-param name="sourceTag" select="'status'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="targetTag" select="'statusInvoice'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="cumulate">
        <xsl:with-param name="sourceTag" select="'date'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="targetTag" select="'dueDate'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="invoiceAmmount"/>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="cumulate">
    <xsl:param name="sourceTag"/>
    <xsl:param name="targetTag"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$targetTag}">
      <xsl:value-of select="*[matches(name(), concat($sourceTag,'\d+'))]" separator=","/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/3MEbY6L

Comment: I was trying to iterate using the ammount of invoices, but I see now that I was on the wrong direction, or at least the hardest one, thank you for showing me this way of transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to use XSLT here is the code you may use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="result">
        <result>
            <invoiceNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="*[matches(name(),'invoice[0-9]')]" separator=","/>    
            </invoiceNumber> 
            <totalAmmount>
                <xsl:value-of select="*[matches(name(),'totalAmmount[0-9]')]" separator=","/>    
            </totalAmmount>
            <statusInvoice>
                <xsl:value-of select="*[matches(name(),'status[0-9]')]" separator=","/>
            </statusInvoice>
            <dueDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="*[matches(name(),'date[0-9]')]" separator=","/>
            </dueDate>
            <invoiceAmmount>3</invoiceAmmount> 
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: if solved the problem with this XSLT please accept the answer.